# How is there the arithmetic error of a division by zero in this function?

Tags: c, cs50, luhn, msvc12

I have written an implementation of *Luhn's algorithm*. When I test the program with numbers that are invalid by the number of digits I get no program error. Instead, the program executes the `printf()` call in the main function. However, whenever I test the program using valid card numbers as per the algorithm I get a division by 0 error. Debugging with DBG gives me an arithmetic error while MSVC gives me a floating point exception, which narrow down to division by 0. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "cs50.h" // For MSVC, I used scanf_s() from stdio.h instead since cs50.h is not supported

long long Prompt(void); // Returns credit card number
int Validate(long long); // Returns checksum
void Report(long long); // Prints success

int main()
{
    long long CardNumber = Prompt();
    int CheckSum = Validate(CardNumber);
    if (!(CheckSum % 10)) {
        Report(CardNumber);
    } else {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

long long Prompt(void)
{
    printf("CARD NUMBER: ");
    long long CardNumber;
    CardNumber = GetLongLong();
    return CardNumber;
}

int Validate(long long CardNumber)
{
    int CheckSum = 0;
    int Digit = 0;
    int DigitCount = (int)(floor(log10l(CardNumber) + 1));
    for (int i = 2; i < DigitCount; i += 2) {
        Digit = 2 * ((CardNumber % (10 ^ i)) / (10 ^ (i - 1))); // BUG
        if (Digit > 9) {
            int BiDigit = Digit;
            Digit = 0;
            int SubDigit = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; i++) {
                SubDigit = (BiDigit % (10 ^ j)) / (10 ^ (j - 1)); // BUG
                Digit += SubDigit;
            }
        }
        CheckSum += Digit;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < DigitCount; i += 2) {
        Digit = (CardNumber % (10 ^ i)) / (10 ^ (i - 1));
        CheckSum += Digit;
    }
    return CheckSum;
}

void Report(long long CardNumber)
{
    int DigitCount = (int)(floor(log10l(CardNumber) + 1));
    int Digit1 = (CardNumber % (10 ^ (DigitCount - 1))) / (10 ^ (DigitCount - 2)); // BUG
    int Digit2 = (CardNumber % (10 ^ (DigitCount - 2))) / (10 ^ (DigitCount - 3)); // BUG
    if (Digit1 == 4 && (DigitCount == 13 || DigitCount == 16))
        printf("VISA\n");
    else if (Digit1 == 3 && (Digit2 == 4 || Digit2 == 7) && DigitCount == 15)
        printf("AMERICAN EXPRESS\n");
    else if (Digit1 == 4 && (Digit2 >= 1 || Digit2 <= 5) && DigitCount == 16)
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    else
        printf("INVALID\n");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Digit = 2 * ((CardNumber % (10 ^ i)) / (10 ^ (i - 1)));
```

`^` is not a power operator, but bitwise xor in `C` and `C++`. Once `i` reaches `10`, the expression `10 ^ i` becomes zero.

---

BTW, in order to get digits from an integral number, it is better to avoid floating point operations (`floor`, `log10l`). A possible algorithm may look like this:

```
int DigitIndex = 0;
while (CardNumber > 0)
{
    int Digit = CardNumber % 10;
    CardNumber /= 10;

    // calculate check sum depending on parity of DigitIndex

    DigitIndex++;       
}
```

Comment: @user295341 Besides this issue, the entire approach does not look right. If you need to get digits of an integer, avoid any float point arithmetic. It just asks for troubles. It is much better to get digit from right to left with repeating of `%10`and `/10`.

Comment: Which is exactly what the loop is doing, provided the fix is done.